# Se puede implementar de manera dinamica los estillos en un proyecto de angular

Tags: css, angular, variables, scss, style

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo un proyecto en angular con scss, mi pregunta es yo creo  2 styles generales con variables uno que se llame cliente1 y otro cliente2. Los dos contienen las mismas variables como $colorprimary por ejemplo pero con diferentes colores uno rojo y otro verde. De manera dinamica en mi caso por la url que una seria cliente1 y otra cliente2 quiero que dependiendo de la url se apliquen las variables genericas del scss.

O si se puede crear un variables.scss añadir variables y dependiendo de la url añadimos unos colores o otros

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: No lo creo, el SCSS se convierte a CSS y todas esas variables pasan a ser constantes. Deberías integrar algo de CSS puro y sus variables (--variable:color) podrías llegar a lo que buscas. Si el cambio es a partir de la URL lo más probable es que requieras un pequeño código Javascript adicional.